# Django: Shut off console output of http response messages

Tags: python, django, http, response

So we made an app with django and it prints all these http response messages on the console everytime it gets a request.

```
[Date String] 'GET /urlpath/..blah blah ' 200 216
[Date String] 'DELETE /anotherurl/..blah blah ' 200 205 
...
..
```

We have disabled all logger outputs. Set Debug=False. Tried 'python manage.py runserver --verbosity 0'.  Even tried changing sys.stdout to a NullDevice() class.  Yet, we can't seem to turn off these response messages which are slowing the server to a crawl. All other messages get turned off, except these.  Any suggestions?

I realize that the django internal webserver is meant only for development and not for production, but we would like to get a fair amount of speed just with the developmental version itself (without having to go into the intricacies of deploying django behind Apache/lighttpd).

Comment: I know printing can be slow but unless you are doing thousands of request per page I really don't think you will benefit from turning these off. And if you are doing thousands of request it will be slow even on proper web server.

Comment: "... we would like to get a fair amount of speed just with the developmental version itself ..." BWAHAHA.

Comment: I'd like to switch these console outputs off, too, at least the ones with HTTP Result code 200.

Comment: There are good reason to filter out certain messages during developement, especially while debugging, to have requests checking if a page has been updated, constantly bombing your debug session, is pretty much unsuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All you need just to Add in Django logging settings:**

```
    'loggers': {
        # django's default logger
        'django.server': {
            'handlers': ['django.server'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
```

you can override Django's default loggers: https://github.com/django/django/blob/32265361279b3316f5bce8efa71f2049409461e3/django/utils/log.py#L18

How Django's default built-in loggers works: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#id3

using custom CallbackFilter filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.CallbackFilter

Comment: This is good information, but I don't understand how to "override Django's default loggers"

Comment: I can't seem to detect these response messages inside a CallbackFilter. When I set a breakpoint inside the callback function, I hit it on every console message except these. If this can really be accomplished with CallbackFilter, a working example would be super helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can let console logging turned on, but with this small patch You can suppress the noisy lines like

```
GET /urlpath/..blah blah ' 200 216
...
```

completely, which **all** have HTTP result code = 200.
In Your Site-packages or VirtualEnv (if You're using it) directory, go to folder structure django / core / servers / basehttp.py

then goto 
Class **WSGIRequestHandler**, 
function def **log_message**(self, format, *args)

After

```
# Don't bother logging requests for admin images or the favicon.
if (self.path.startswith(self.admin_media_prefix)
        or self.path == '/favicon.ico'):
    return
```

Insert

```
# START ----- Don't show page requests which have run successfully
if args[1] == '200':
    return
# END ----- Don't show page requests which have run successfully
```

This is a dirty work-around for Python 2.7.3, Django 1.4.3, I am interested in a clean customization, also :-)

Comment: This worked just fine for me. I always hesitate to modify library code, but in this case it seems fully justified. I found I was also interested in preventing `304` responses from being displayed as well; instead of `if args[1] == '200':` I used `if args[1] in ['200', '304',]:`. This answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in development server was not designed for performance, instead use [`gunicorn`](http://gunicorn.org/run.html#gunicorn-django). You can add it as an app to your Django project and it will make a command `run_gunicorn` available to you, as an alternative to `runserver`. It's a fair bit faster and more responsive than the built-in development server. If you want you can also set gunicorn's logging level with `--log-level`. It's also fairly simple to deploy, and suitable for production.

Comment: It's a bit more complex than that, as gunicorn does not start automatically when making a change to your project's .py files, so you have to set up restarting manually.